# ReferenceError: require is not defined in Angular 4.0.0

Tags: angular

I am working with angular 4.0.0. and I got this error in browser console:

```
addScript.js:8 [Script Loader] ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:20), <anonymous>:4:13)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:20)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../chart.js/src/chart.js (chart.js?6e13:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 666c8e57b842ded4b2e3:54)
    at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:157)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 666c8e57b842ded4b2e3:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 666c8e57b842ded4b2e3:25)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
```

I checked other issue but no solution posted. I read somewhere that is a bug in angular. Any solution to fix it ? 
Thanks in advance

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show tsconfig.json ?

Comment: @dark_gf i have edited the post

Comment: Hm, looks good, did you check latest version of angular?
Or can you somehow show complete project (push it to github and show link)?